# log4net RolllingFileAppender and file name pattern

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

I'm using a RollingFileAppender with log4net with the following configuration:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value=".\Logs\log-file.txt" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d[%2t] %p %logger{1}.%M | %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

As you can see, a new file is created after a 10MB limit per file is reached. Every file (except the first one) ends with a number which is incremented when a new file is created.
Despite my researches, I still have two problems:

- the first file does not have any number at the end (I'd like the first file to be named "logfile.1.txt")
- the older files are deleted and the file name's numbers are incremented, that's great, but I'd like the numbers to be between 1 and 5 only.

Does anyone have any idea how I can have the behavior above?

Many thanks !